# Query duration in MySQL General log

Tags: mysql

MySQL has feature of logging all sql queries - [General log](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/query-log.html).

But this log does not contain queries durations.

How to log all sql queries to analyze those durations?

Comment: The is some mysql-slow.log or similar, it logs the queries whose execution time was longer as a specific duration. You can configure this value. I can't remember the exact details, probably it is somewhere in my.cnf. Hopefully others will give you a full-featured answer.

Answer (score 1):

I got an answer after writing a question, but i want to share it to community.

Just set up [Slow log](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/slow-query-log.html) and set `SET GLOBAL long_query_time = 0`.

You will see all sql queries with durations in slow log file.

Comment: And once you have done that, use `pt-query-digest` or `mysqldumpslow -s t` to discover the 'worst' queries and deal with them.